# Fresh install with minimal: missing manage display even with field_ui turned on

Tags: 7, entities

I just installed a fresh copy of Drupal 7 and chose the minimal install option. I enabled `field_ui` and I still do not see the **manage display** tab on content pages. However it does show up when you goto the content type directly. Did i forget to click somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying **Manage Display** tab on content page you have to install [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

On drupal core no such module or configuration  that display this tab on content page. So you didn't forget anything for this.